Preserving non-conjugacy of loxodromic isometries in a Dehn filling
Suppose that $g$ and $h$ are non-conjugate loxodromic isometries in a cusped hyperbolic $3$-manifold $M$ of finite volume.  Fix a cusp $T$ of $M$. Can I choose a hyperbolic Dehn filling of $M$ along $T$ such that the images of $g$ and $h$ remain (a) loxodromic and (b) non-conjugate in the filled manifold?

It follows from geometric convergence of the filled manifolds to the original manifold.

It follows from the comment of Moisha Kohan above.
Another way to see it: take the closed oriented geodesics $\gamma, \eta$ in $M$ realizing the monodromy of $g$ and $h$ respectively. Since $g$ and $h$ are non-conjugate, they are distinct as oriented closed geodesics (note though that they could have multiplicity or intersect). Choose a horocusp $H$ disjoint from the images of $\gamma \cup \eta$. Choose a loop $\sigma$ in the boundary of $H$ which has length $> 2\pi$. Then by the proof of the $2\pi$ theorem, one may perform a filling along the slope $\sigma$ which removes $H$ and replaces it with a negatively curved metric on a solid torus so that the resulting manifold is negatively curved. Then the geodesic immersions $\gamma, \eta$ are still distinct in this metric, and hence represent non-conjugate elements in the fundamental group.
